# Why can't special controllers or accessories be used with Super FX games?

Tags: hardware, snes

SNES games with the Super FX processor generally do not support special controllers or accessories such as the Multi Player 5 multitap, SNES Mouse, or Super Scope. *Yoshi's Island*, for example, displays this error message when the console is turned on with such a device inserted:

> This game is designed only to play with a normal controller. Please disconnect Mouse, Super Scope, etc. to begin playing.

Why do Super FX games have this limitation?

Comment: That question is clearly of topic, as it's about a game system and gaming. None of the items touched are computing related. You may be better off to move it onto a gaming related SE site.

Comment: This is a *technical question* about the operation of the console, not related to actual gameplay. The SNES is considered on-topic for this site.

Comment: As you say, a **game console** - which **isn't** a computer - and about the **game** operation on that console, not in any way **computing related**.  And the SNES is on topic in relation due its computing dimension, not gaming. It 'perfectly' fails the test proposed in [this meta question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/709/6659) as there is a proper site for this kind of questions: [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) (or Arqade). Moving it over there might sensible decision.

Comment: And ultimately, this is a question about historical game hardware not related to gameplay. The answer involves the technical details of the operation of the hardware. If this was a question about actual gameplay, it would belong on [gaming.se], but this has nothing to do with actually playing a game. It's a question related to the Super FX processor and accessories attached to the console.

Comment: [This question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1380) is more intrinsically related to the actual use of the console as a gaming device, yet ultimately involves technical operation of the historical hardware. And [this mod comment to the Meta answer you referred to](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/703#comment1198_709) states that this is not a good indication of the scope of this site. I'd follow the answers to these questions: https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2 and https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/47

Comment: @Raffzahn That question is very clearly on topic to me. Even if it were only about "game system and gaming", consoles are still considered on topic here. Whether it is interesting, is another question. But even boring questions are in topic here.

Comment: @bwDraco Judging by prior consensus, this kind of question _is_ on-topic. But a comment on meta having been written by a moderator doesn't generally give it extra weight on _scope_ issues.

Comment: @Raffzahn Note that this machine was marketed in Japan as the "Super Family Computer". Its primary purpose is as a games console, but it runs BASIC. The line between "computer" and "games console" is either blurry or marketing, and judging by both hardware and marketing this counts as a computing device more so than some other on-topic devices; it's even user-programmable.

Comment: [This is being discussed on meta.](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/711/278)

Comment: I'm overruling this closure [along with three others](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/review/close/6025); the question is on-topic, as per [this meta answer](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/44/278).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

SNES cartridges equipped with the Super FX processor use significantly more power than normal game cartridges. If a Super FX game is used with special controllers or accessories, which can use more power than normal controllers, it is possible to overload the stock AC adapter.

As such, with limited exceptions, Super FX games must check the accessories inserted into the console at startup and display an error message instead of starting the game if it finds anything other than a normal controller. From the [SNES development manual](https://archive.org/details/SNESDevManual), book II, page 2-1-5 (via [this forum thread](http://www.smwcentral.net/?p=viewthread&t=17876&page=1)):

[image: Super FX safety program requirement]

> #### 1.5.7 — Current Consumption
>
> A game pak which contains the Super FX is required to have a built-in safety program to prevent it from operating in excess of the maximum current rating of the AC Adapter. For example, a game pak which contains the Super FX can not be used with Multi Player 5 because this would exceed the maximum current rating. A program must be included within the game pak which will check accessory IDs and activate the Super FX only if an acceptable accessory is connected. If an accessory ID other than those acceptable is detected, a warning message must be displayed and the Super FX must halt.
>
> Some accessories may be used, depending upon the size of ROM and RAM included in the game pak and the Super FX operating frequency. [...]